# Ionic Http request re-occurring multiple times

Tags: ionic-framework, service, httprequest

I'm learning Ionic and stuck on an issue. My app is stuck in a loop in which it is repeatedly fetching information from a remote server and causing the browser and crash.

[image]

I setup a service, code below, to retrieve the data:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
  Generated class for the CategoriesServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesServiceProvider {

  apiURL = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello CategoriesServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getUsers(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.apiURL).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
        // console.log(data);
      }, err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Below is the code in my *categories.ts* file which uses the service above:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CategoriesServiceProvider } from '../../providers/categories-service/categories-service';

/**
 * Generated class for the CategoriesPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-categories',
  templateUrl: 'categories.html',
  providers: [CategoriesServiceProvider]
})
export class CategoriesPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private categories: CategoriesServiceProvider) {
  }

  users: any;

  getUsers(){
    this.categories.getUsers().then(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CategoriesPage');
    this.getUsers();
  }

}
```

... followed by *categories.html*:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>categories</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
      TESTING - {{user.gender}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I don't know why the http request is repeating instead of fetching once and then going away.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are looping on the function to get your data:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
      TESTING - {{user.gender}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Replace it with the retrieved data instead!

Something like :

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of this.users">
      TESTING - {{user.gender}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```